# Seaborn graph visualization

Tags: python, seaborn

I have created a jointplot graph in seaborn using jupiter. For some reason the output graph has different visualization-  I wish to have grid on the background.
I have seen few examples and I think my code is the same but for some reason I can't get the same visualization.

This is how I would like my plot to look like-

[image]

and this is how my output looks like-

[image]

this is the code I have used. th epart of importing the data is missing.-

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)
sns.jointplot(data=data, x= 'Time on Website', y='Yearly Amount Spent')
```

My goal is to have the grid as background with resembling output to the first graph.

Comment: Try calling `plt.grid(True)` (after importing matplotlib)

Comment: this one just add empty grid plot in addition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sns.set_style("whitegrid")`, here a simple example:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.jointplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
```

this is the output:

[image]